# C# class instance attribute mechanism

Tags: c#, templates

Is there a sane way in C# to achieve the following construct (in pseudocode):

```
void Method(MyClass<Attribute1, Attribute2, ...> foo)
{
  // here I am guaranteed that foo has the specified attributes
}
```

Where `Attribute*` are, for example, enum values, such that only instances of `MyClass` instantiated with the attributes required by the method can be passed to the method (and otherwise fail to compile)?

I tried looking at generics since I know that C++ templates can make this work so it seemed like a logical starting point, but I couldn't get it working elegantly (I tried using interfaces to constrain the types of the parameter in this fashion but it was very bulky and frankly unusable since I have at least 4 attributes).

I want to do this to avoid having lots of annoying checks at the beginning of each method. I am doing DirectX 11 graphics development so I am kind of constrained by the API which does not make it particularly easy to pass objects around in this "type-safe" manner (in DirectX every resource has a large "Description" structure which contains information about what the resource can and cannot do, is and is not, etc.. and is tedious and error-prone to parse, so I am trying to write a wrapper around it for my and my users' convenience).

I also cannot have different class types for every case because there are a lot of combinations, so this seems like the most comfortable way to write code like this, and I am hoping C# makes this possible.

---

I'm sure there is a name for this kind of language feature (if you know it please let me know, I would have googled but this is kind of hard to search for when you don't know the proper keywords...)

Comment: Do you want to allow only certain values to be passed to your method, or is your question about how to constrain a generic method to accept only certain types?

Comment: @elgonzo Not so much "types", but a given class with a set of attributes, e.g. for a texture class I'd have a method which only accepts, say, a 4-channel texture with 32 bits per channel (so that'd be two attributes) and the method would only accept Texture instances instantiated with the "4 channels" and "32 bits per channel" attributes. So it's kind of in between generics and full-blown metaprogramming, but it's really unwieldy to implement using generics and type covariance mechanisms.

Comment: Create a type that represents 4-channel, 32bpc textures, and constrain your Method to this type. (Inherit it from a base class that implements common stuff for different texture types, so that you don't end up with spaghetti code...)

Comment: @elgonzo I can't do that. I also have mipmapping attributes, many other formats, CPU access restrictions, pipeline bind flags.. there are too many combinations to sanely create a subtype out of each.

Comment: Okay, then you will have to do the sanity checks in your method, unfortunately. Generic type parameters in .NET must be types themselves. You can't create a generic type/method that is specific to a particular value of the Generic type parameter only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generic type parameters in .NET must be types themselves. You can't create a generic type/method that is specific to a particular value of the Generic type parameter only.

If you do not want or cannot create a type that represents the attribute values you want your method being restricted to, you will have to do sanity checks in your method to ensure that the proper attribute values are used in the provided "foo" object.

Using specific types as representation of specific attribute values might be an answer for the problem you asked about, but it has the disadvantage of not supporting switch-case statements (see further below). Please also read the final note at the end of my answer.

Say, you want a type that represents textures. Textures can have different number of channels, and different bit depths. You could then declare a generic texture type like this:

```
class Texture<TChannels, TBPC>
    where TChannels : INumOfChannels,new()
    where TBPC : IBitsPerChannel,new()
```

*INumOfChannels* and *IBitsPerChannel* are just interfaces and can be empty.
The *new()* constraint prevents creation of a concrete Texture type by using the interfaces themselves.

For different channels and different BPCs, you will create empty types extending from the respective base interfaces, for example:

```
class FourChannels : INumOfChannels {};
class ThreeChannels : INumOfChannels {};

class BitsPerChannel_24 : IBitsPerChannel {};
class BitsPerChannel_32 : IBitsPerChannel {};
```

Using this, you can restrict your generic method to certain attribute combinations. In case your method should only deal with 4-channel and 32bpc textures:

```
void MyMethod<TChannels, TBPC>(Texture<TChannels, TBPC> foo)
    where TChannels : FourChannels
    where TBPC : BitsPerChannel_32
```

Now, every good thing also has dark sides. How would you do something like this (written as pseudo-code)?

```
switch (NumOfChannelsAttribute)
{
    case FourChannels:
        // do something
        break;

    case ThreeChannels:
        // do something else
        break;
}
```

You can't, at least not in an easy and simple way, because "FourChannel" and "ThreeChannel" are types, not integral values.

Of course, you can still use *if* constructs. For this to work you would need to implement a property in the generic texture type which provides the used attributes:

```
class Texture<TChannels, TBPC> where TChannels : INumOfChannels,new() where TBPC : IBitsPerChannel,new()
{
    public Type ChannelsAttribute
    {
        get { return typeof(TChannels); }
    }

    public Type BitsPerChannelAttribute
    {
        get { return typeof(TBPC); }
    }
}
```

In an *if* construct, you could utilize this as follows:

```
var myTex = new Texture<FourChannels, BitsPerChannel_32>();

if (myTex.ChannelsAttribute == typeof(FourChannels))
{
    ... do something with 4 channels
}
else
{
    ... though luck, only 4 channels are supported...
}
```

A final note and advice:
While this might work for your problem, resorting to these kind of 'tricks' usually is an indication of a flawed design. I think it is well-invested time if you revisit the design choices you made in your code, so you don't need to rely on crutches like this.

Answer (score 1):

C# doesn't have such a feature. You mention you have tried using interfaces, but don't specify how. The way I'd suggest you try using them is by using generics with multiple constraints, eg

```
void Method(T foo) where T : IAttribute1, IAttribute2, IAttribute3, IAttribute4
{
}
```

Let's say one such attribute class is then ICpuMappable, then you can constrain types that can be used with `Method1` with:

```
void Method1(T foo) where T : ICpuMappable
{
}
```

and you can know any `foo` passed to `Method1` is CPU mappable.

You'll likely end up with lots of interfaces, but as many will be treated as "flags", they shouldn't be too difficult to maintain.

Comment: How would this approach deal with self-contradictory class instances? With this approach it would still be possible to instantiate `foo` with, for instance, `ICpuMappable` and `IImmutable`, would the constructor handle this to forbid such combinations?

Comment: What do you mean with "self-contradictory"? If IImmutable would extend one of the IAttribute interfaces, then the the constraint would be fulfilled. If IImutable does not extend those IAttribute interfaces, then the compiler would reject your code.

Comment: @elgonzo Well taking the example in my response to your comment on the question, `IFourChannels` and `IThreeChannels`. They both extend `IAttribute`, but they are meaningless together... so no instance of `foo` should be able to be instantiated with both. How do I enforce this?

Comment: You can't do that. But according to the comments attached to your question, you could perhaps do something like this: Create separate base interfaces INumberOfChannels and IBitsPerChannel. Your MyClass type would be a generic type like "MyClass<INumberOfChannels, IBitsPerChannel>". You would then have an attribute implementation like "FourChannel : INumberOfChannels", "ThreeChannel : INumberOfChannels", as well as for example "BPC_32 : IBitsPerChannel" and "BPC_24 : IBitsPerChannel". You could then restrict your method to `where Attribute1 : FourChannel, Attribute2 : BPC_32`

Comment: Addendum to my last comment: This becomes of course more difficult in other parts of your code, where you might have to do something like if-then-else or switch-case based on those attributes. Without knowing exactly what your code looks like, it is hard to give a precise and correct answer. :-(

Comment: @elgonzo That is quite clever and seems like what I was looking for (a bit verbose, granted, but still effective) could you maybe post this as an answer?

Comment: If a class implements both IFourChannels and IThreeChannels, then one of two things has to happen: the resultant class needs to support both 3 and 4 channel operations (not your problem) or you can writing code to check for such combinations (your problem). It's your choice how you handle it.

Comment: Having caught up with the comments, I like @elgonzo's suggestion better than my "someone have to deal with it" suggestion.